# OS X Lion VNC no longer works

Tags: vnc, ipad, osx-lion, screen-sharing, vncserver

I enjoyed using VNC from my iPad to my Mac Pro running Snow Leopard without issues. Since upgrading to OS X Lion, I am no longer able to log in remotely.

I can connect, but I now see the OS X login screen instead of my desktop. I can't type my password either.

I read that changes to the Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) protocol in Lion have rendered VNC (aka Screen Sharing) unusable in many cases. Does anyone have a workaround? I'm using Mocha VNC Lite on my iPad.

Answer (score 2):

[Seems like](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3191186) a feature not yet available in Mocha VNC. Other clients [seem to work now](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/07/screens-vnc-client-gets-updated-adds-support-for-os-x-lion-other-improvements), so it's probably just a matter of time for Mocha VNC to receive an update.

You need to send username and password over VNC for authenticating. [This answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15685764#15685764) seems to suggest a solution:

> [...] by making a simple macro: `#T` username (no space) then your password (no space) `#R`. When you see the login screen recall this marco and then press the enter arrow in VNC and you will log into Lion.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I'm still on the hunt for a free VNC client for iPad that works with Lion.

Comment: Hm, you might want to give the developers some time to catch up. In the meantime  I heard that [Remoter](http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/remoter-remote-desktop-vnc/id369626098?mt=8) works, and it currently is only $ .99

Comment: The [screens app from edovia](http://www.edovia.com/screens) does work well - mac and iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to use the vanilla VNC server instead of the "Apple" one that requires both a username and password to authenticate.

If you go into System Preferences->Sharing and turn off the "Screen Sharing" service, then turn on "Remote Management" and click "Computer Settings" you can enter a password only (which is how most VNC client expect to authenticate).
[image: VNC Server in OS X]